# Get value from json output when [0] can be a random number

Tags: php, json

I need to the get "lastvalue" from json output.
It's a Zabbix json output and 3 (random) parts of it looks like this below.
My question is, how can i get "lastvalue" when **[0]** can be a random number? For example **[21]** or **[7]**.

**["name"]=> string(17)** seems to be only thing that matches every time.
I'm trying to make simplified view over zabbix API, i'm able to get hostname etc, but this is over my head at the moment.
I'll try to answer every question as detailed as possible if someone has one.
And please correct me if my question is poorly formatted.

```
array(56) {
    [0]=>
        array(4) {
            ["itemid"]=>
                string(5) "24117"
            ["name"]=>
                string(17) "Ping Zabbix Agent"
            ["key_"]=>
                string(10) "agent.ping"
            ["lastvalue"]=>
                string(1) "1"
        }
############################
    [21]=>
        array(4) {
            ["itemid"]=>
                string(5) "24020"
            ["name"]=>
                string(17) "Ping Zabbix Agent"
            ["key_"]=>
                string(10) "agent.ping"
            ["lastvalue"]=>
                string(1) "1"
        }
############################
    [7]=>
        array(4) {
            ["itemid"]=>
                string(5) "24065"
            ["name"]=>
                string(17) "Ping Zabbix Agent"
            ["key_"]=>
                string(10) "agent.ping"
            ["lastvalue"]=>
                string(1) "1"
        }
```

**EDIT**
Here is the foreach part:

```
foreach ($data['result'] as $key) {
echo "<td>".$key['name']."</td></b>";
echo "<td>".$key['items'][1]['lastvalue']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$url.$key['hostid']."\"target='_blank'>Link</a>"."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

This `[1]` can be different number as i wrote before.

Comment: The [end](http://php.net/end) function will return the value at the last key in an array.

Comment: You want ALL `lastvalue` or just the first one in the `0` array?  How do you know that you want the one from `0` and not the one from `7`???

Comment: @AbraCadaver i want ALL `lastvalue` values.

Comment: @Jaur Can you post expected output?

Comment: There is a confusion when you using foreach `$key` will be getting you every array of your `$data` so if you want to extract `lastvalue` you can easily get it by using `$key['lastvalue']` why are you using `$key['items'][1]['lastvalue']` is there any other array within `$key`?